# Are the Ilvermorny houses based on the Hogwarts houses?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, fantastic-beasts

I did some research, and it seems like some of the houses in Ilvermorny are related to the houses in Hogwarts. Horned Serpent seems like Ravenclaw, and Pukwudgie seems like Hufflepuff, but I'm not sure about the others. Can anyone explain whether the houses if Ilvermorny were indeed inspired by Hogwarts and if so their similarities?

Comment: It might help if you tell us about your "research".

Comment: And what Ilvermorny is - I know I've seen it before, but I can't recall the context.

Comment: I've voted to reopen. From the title I was expecting this to be "not clear" or "opinion based"  but @Bellatrix has provided a really solid answer from both in- and out-of-universe perspectives.

Comment: Hogwarts house system is actually loosely based on Oxbridge college system. Being British, there is no way Rowling wouldn't know about the Oxbridge system. So whatever ilvermony houses are, there is a good chance they mimick the same structure. As a side note, for people studying in Cambridge or Oxford, HP provides the very best analogy to describe the difference between college, university, class and department to people from other countries.

Comment: @RDFozz Ilvermony is the American school for witchcraft and wizardry. Introduced in Fantastic Beasts (I think?)

Comment: @C.Koca I think that the house system at Hogwarts is more analogous to the ones in Public Schools such as Rugby, Harrow and Eton  than Oxford and Cambridge Universities.

Comment: @C.Koca Hogwarts was founded at least a hundred years before Oxford, so if we’re splitting hairs, the Oxbridge college system is like Hogwarts houses, not the other way around. ;-)

Answer (score 16):

## No, the Hogwarts Houses don’t have direct analogs in Ilvermorny.

The Hogwarts Houses are Slytherin (for the cunning and ambitious), Ravenclaw (for those who value knowledge), Hufflepuff (for the kind and loyal), and Gryffindor (for the brave). The Houses in Ilvermorny are Horned Serpent (favors scholars), Wampus (favors warriors), Thunderbird (favors adventurers), and Pukwudgie (favors healers). However, the houses in Ilvermorny are also sometimes said to represent different parts of a wizard as well.

> It is sometimes said of the Ilvermorny houses that they represent the whole witch or wizard: the mind is represented by Horned Serpent; the body, Wampus; the heart, Pukwudgie and the soul, Thunderbird. Others say that Horned Serpent favours scholars, Wampus, warriors, Pukwudgie, healers and Thunderbird, adventurers. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Ilvermorny School of Witchcraft and Wizardry (Pottermore)](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/ilvermorny)*</sup></sub>

A few of the Houses do seem very similar, though. Like the question itself states, Horned Serpent and Ravenclaw are alike in that they favor students who value learning. Wampus has some parallels to Gryffindor, as warriors are often braver than most. Thunderbird *also* has parallels to Gryffindor, as they seek adventure, a common Gryffindor trait. There’s no definite indicator that one is “more” Gryffindor than the other, Pukwudgie may relate somewhat to Hufflepuff, as Healers are most likely kind-hearted if they choose that as their profession. However, not all kind people are good at being or want to be Healers, and (if it’s anything like in the Muggle world) not all Healers would be kind.

There is no equivalent or similar House to Slytherin in Ilvermorny. None of the Ilvermorny Houses value cunning or ambition, and none of the traits valued by the individual Ilvermorny Houses are traits specifically valued by Slytherin.

For whatever it’s worth, J.K. Rowling denied in a [tweet](https://mobile.twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/748047129814437888) that the Houses have direct equivalents.

[image]

## The *idea* to have houses was based on Hogwarts, though.

The reason Ilvermorny has houses, though, was directly because Hogwarts had houses, and the Boot brothers had grown up knowing Hogwarts and their thoughts on what their magical school should be like were built around it.

> The boys’ ideas of what a magical school ought to be like were based almost entirely on Hogwarts, so they insisted that it ought to have four houses. The idea of naming the houses after themselves, as the founders, was swiftly abandoned, because Webster felt a house called ‘Webster Boot’ had no chance of ever winning anything, and instead, each chose their favourite magical beast. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Ilvermorny School of Witchcraft and Wizardry (Pottermore)](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/ilvermorny)*</sup></sub>

The houses themselves were based on the family members’ favorite magical creatures, and they eventually gave some of their characteristics to them as well, though seemingly not as intentionally as the Hogwarts founders did.

> For Chadwick, an intelligent but often temperamental boy, it was the Thunderbird that can create storms as it flies. For argumentative but fiercely loyal Webster, it was the Wampus, a magical panther-like creature that was fast, strong and almost impossible to kill. For Isolt, it was, of course, the Horned Serpent that she still visited and with which she felt a strange sense of kinship.
>
> When asked what his favourite creature was, James was at a loss. The only No-Maj in the family was unable to consort with the magical creatures the others had begun to know well. Finally, he named the Pukwudgie, because the stories his wife told of curmudgeonly William always made him laugh.
>
> Thus were the four houses of Ilvermorny created, and while the four originators did not yet know it, much of their own characters leaked into the houses they had so light-heartedly named. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Ilvermorny School of Witchcraft and Wizardry (Pottermore)](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/ilvermorny)*</sup></sub>

Comment: Of course, the jock had to be called Chadwick.

Comment: In the tweet, why is JKR assuming that Hufflepuff is being put down? What am I missing?

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd I’m guessing because the person she’s replying to says if Wampus is equivalent to Hufflepuff they’re going to cry in a corner. JKR is probably thinking they’re a Wampus who doesn’t want their Ilvermorny house to be equivalent to Hufflepuff.

Comment: It could also be read as a Hufflepuff not wanting to be compared to a Wampus

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd Yeah - I’m not sure which one it is though. I’d guess that it’s more likely they don’t want to be Hufflepuff, because there’s more information about the Hogwarts houses than the Ilvermorny houses, and Hufflepuff is sometimes seen as the “leftover” house. There isn’t much information about Wampus other than that it favors warriors and possibly represents the heart. There’s nothing really to give the first impression that it’s a bad house to be in.

Comment: Given the body type of most Hufflepuffs, I really doubt there's any *leftovers* there at all. ;)

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd Haha! ;) Maybe they’re called the “leftover house” because they eat all the leftovers! ;)

Comment: I'm proud to serve under Madam Helga. ;)

Answer (score -1):

From what i can tell then are slight connections between the houses in Ilvermorny and the houses in Hogwarts but no direct connection, **But we know for sure the idea for the houses was based on Hogwarts**

> The boys’ ideas of what a magical school ought to be like were based almost entirely on Hogwarts, so they insisted that it ought to have four houses.
>   -[*Ilvermorny School of Witchcraft and Wizardry - Pottermore*](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/ilvermorny)

One of the more obvious differences between Hogwarts and Ilvermorny is that Ilvermornies houses werent named after the founders of the school.

> The idea of naming the houses after themselves, as the founders, was swiftly abandoned, because Webster felt a house called ‘Webster Boot’ had no chance of ever winning anything, and instead, each chose their favourite magical beast.
>   [*Ilvermorny School of Witchcraft and Wizardry - Pottermore*](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/ilvermorny)

One similarity that we can see is that some of the founders attributes/personality is reflected in the Houses

> Thus were the four houses of Ilvermorny created, and while the four originators did not yet know it, much of their own characters leaked into the houses they had so light-heartedly named.
>   [*Ilvermorny House of Witchcraft and Wizardry - Pottermore*](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/ilvermorny)

Heres a quote about Hogwarts

> As The Sorting Hat told us, their reason for doing so was because they had the ‘selfsame yearning, to make the world’s best magic school’, and once they did, **each created their own house to represent a personality and skill that they wanted to nurture.**
>   [*The origins of Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry - Pottermore*](https://www.pottermore.com/features/origins-of-hogwarts-school-of-witchcraft-and-wizardry)

(Highlight is mine)